# WPS Process JTS:dimension

Tags: wps

I'm simply trying to call a WPS process " JTS:dimension ". Code for executing this process is as shown below. I am able to configure this process but not execute it.

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
{
    allOverlays: true,
    center: [114, 16],
    zoom: 4,
    layers: [new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector()]
});

var features = [new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector
                (OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT
                (
                'LINESTRING(117 22,112 18,118 13, 115 8)'
                ))];

var cbl = document.getElementById("cb1");
cb1.onchange = fea;
var cb2 = document.getElementById("cb2");
cb2.onchange = dim;

function fea()
{
    if(cb1.checked)
    map.baseLayer.addFeatures(features);

    else
    return; 
}

var client = new OpenLayers.WPSClient({
    servers: {
            opengeo: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wps'
    }
    });


function dim()
{
if (cb2.checked)
{
var dime = client.getProcess('local','JTS:dimension');
        dime.configure(
            {
                inputs:
                {
                    geom: features
                }
            });
        console.log("geometry type configured");
        dime.execute(
            {
                inputs:
                {
                    geom: features
                },
                success: function(outputs)
                {
                    console.log(outputs);                   
                }
            });
}
else
return;
}
```

when i execute this code i am getting an Openlayers error as shown below :

"  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'processDescription' of undefined "

Please help me with this error.

Comment: I think you've misspelled the name of the variable `cb1` when you defined it, could that be the source of the error?